# How to pass text box value to php during run time?

Tags: javascript, php

When user save the records to database, i checked the records of saved data. If the record is already existed in database, ask user whether overwrite or cancel using message box. I want to get the user response OK or Cancel.

First, i call js function during run time from php. JS function shows confirm message and pass the return value to hidden text box. This part is working fine.

But, i couldn't pass the text box value to php variable.

```js
<script>

function confirmOverwrite() {
        var overwriterec = "";
        if(confirm("Do you want to overwrite the record? Click on OK to overwrite.Click Cancel to skip."))
            overwriterec="ok";
        }
        else
        {
            overwriterec="cancel";
        }
        document.getElementById("hiddenVal").value = overwriterec;
}
</script>
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
    <div>
      <button  type="submit" name="Save"> Save data</button>
     <input type="text" style="display:none" id="hiddenVal" name="overwrite" />
    </div>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["Save"])){
$Sql = "SELECT * FROM maintable WHERE userid='$userid'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $Sql);
                                  
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
   {
   
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
           'confirmOverwrite();',
           '</script>';           //can call the function and pass the OK or Cancel value to hidden text box.

        if((isset($_POST['overwrite'])) && !empty($_POST['overwrite']))
        {
          $Confirmation = $_POST['overwrite']; //I can't pass the hidden text box value to php variable.
           echo $Confirmation;
         }

         if ($Confirmation == "ok")
         {
           // update the record
         }
   }
  }

}
?>
```

Comment: You can use a 'hidden' input type instead of hiding a normal text input using CSS. `<input type="text" style="display:none" id="hiddenVal" name="overwrite" />` would become `<input type="hidden" id="hiddenVal" name="overwrite" />`

Comment: Are you only posting the form once?  Or twice?  Your sequence of events seems to require posting it twice.  And you're showing the confirmation dialog both times.  This sequence of events is very strange...

Comment: Program asks user whenever it founds the save record data is already existed in database. For example, if program finds two existing records, confirm box will pop up twice and get the response twice too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the function before from submit.
I have added one alert of hidden value.

```
if(isset($_POST["Save"])){
  if((isset($_POST['overwrite'])) && !empty($_POST['overwrite']))
  {
    $Confirmation = $_POST['overwrite']; //I can't pass the hidden text box value to php variable.
    echo $Confirmation
  }
}
```

```js
function confirmOverwrite() {
    var overwriterec = "";
    if (confirm('Do you want to overwrite the record? Click on OK to overwrite.Click Cancel to skip.')) {
        overwriterec="ok";
    } else {
        overwriterec="cancel";
    }
    document.getElementById('hiddenVal').value = overwriterec;
    alert(document.getElementById('hiddenVal').value);
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="confirmOverwrite()">
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" id="hiddenVal" name="overwrite" />
      <button  type="submit" name="Save"> Save data</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Client side code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Client Side</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
function savedata(confirm){
    httpRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open("POST", "savescript.php",true);
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange=saved;
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpRequest.send("confirm="+confirm);
}

function saved(){
    readyState=httpRequest.readyState;
    if(readyState!=4) return;

    httpStatus=httpRequest.status;
    if(httpStatus!=200) return;

    var phpResponse=httpRequest.responseText;

    if(phpResponse==1){ //ask for confirm if the server send back 1
        if(confirm("This record already exists. Are you sure to overwrite this record?")) savedata('yes');
    }
    else savedata('yes');
}
</script>

<p>The example form: </p>
...Other inputs...<br/>
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="savedata('no')"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Server side code:

```
<?php
/***********SEVER SIDE CODE (savescript.php)*************/

//Connection to database (mysqli_connect)

$query=mysqli_query($connection_to_db,"your query to check if the record exists");

$confirm=$_POST['confirm']; //the client side confirmation variable

if($confirm=='yes'){ //if the user has confirmed
    //if the record exists update else insert
    if(mysqli_num_row($query)==1) mysqli_query($connection_to_db,"your query to update the record");
    else mysqli_query($connection_to_db,"your query to insert the record");
}
else{   //if the user did not confirm

    if(mysqli_num_row($query)==1) echo("1"); //send 1 this means that the record exists then the client ask for confirm
    else echo("0"); //send 0 this means that the record doesn't exists then you can insert without ask confirm
}
?>
```